# How to get Column Level permission in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: permissions, column

I require column level permissions in SharePoint 2010.

In MOSS 2007 I was using [SPListDisplaySetting](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/). However, it does not work for SP2010.

Anybody has an alternative solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story for SP2010 is the same as for MOSS: no column level permission. You do need either third party tools or code your own event handler logic where you control who can see what.

Comment: Bamboo had a column level security product for 2007, I haven't checked to see if that got ported over to 2010 or not.

Comment: Hi thanks....Any free solutions?

Comment: none that i tried. Try to google it

Comment: Have bought Smart List Pro from Infowise which is really good. I am not marketing their product here but since there are no solutions available ... The app I use may help many.